# opencart error I can't move to sever I fine error with path file missing

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin, phpunit

opencart I try to move but I get error 
like this

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in /www/zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/index.php on line 15

Warning: require_once(http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/startup.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /www/zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/index.php on line 15

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /www/zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/index.php on line
```

15

so I chnaged configue file

to

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.rasvi.zxq.net/shop/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.rasvi.zxq.net/shop/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.rasvi.zxq.net/shop/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.rasvi.zxq.net/shop/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://www.rasvi.zxq.net/shop/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'http://zxq.net/r/a/s/rasvi/htdocs/shop/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'rasvi_zxq_shop');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'sh_');
?>
```

i wanna what is wrong with my configue file I made DB and import all tables

Answer (score 0):

Use the server base path `/home/yoursite/public_html/` instead of `sitename`